# How do I work out the significance of main effects in negative binomial models with more than two factors?

Tags: statistical-significance, interaction, negative-binomial-distribution, likelihood-ratio, main-effects

I am trying to look at how the number of events X is affected by the three factors A (4 levels), B (2 levels) and C (2 levels) using a negative binomial model as follows:

```
model.count.nb<-glm.nb(X.total ~ A*B*C, link = "log", data = count.X)
summary(model.count.nb)

Call:
glm.nb(formula = X.total ~ A * B * C, 
    data = count.X, link = "log", init.theta = 4.864199324)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.7430  -0.5601   0.0705   0.4939   2.0461  

Coefficients:
                                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                           5.529870   0.152589  36.240   <2e-16 ***
A2                                   -0.011079   0.193019  -0.057    0.954    
A3                                    0.060288   0.215733   0.279    0.780    
A4                                   -0.270010   0.206022  -1.311    0.190    
B2                                    0.098550   0.215697   0.457    0.648    
C2                                   -0.249439   0.205999  -1.211    0.226    
A2:B2                                 0.095448   0.300565   0.318    0.751    
A3:B2                                -0.001116   0.281570  -0.004    0.997    
A4:B2                                 0.330682   0.302998   1.091    0.275    
A2:C2                                 0.244077   0.282310   0.865    0.387    
A3:C2                                -0.215565   0.294696  -0.731    0.464    
A4:C2                                 0.172165   0.276917   0.622    0.534    
B2:C2                                -0.137896   0.303376  -0.455    0.649    
A2:B2:C2                             -0.025005   0.440519  -0.057    0.955    
A3:B2:C2                              0.401948   0.396986   1.012    0.311    
A4:B2:C2                              0.027745   0.403595   0.069    0.945    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(4.8642) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 221.54  on 185  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 193.99  on 170  degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 2280.9

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  4.864 
          Std. Err.:  0.505 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -2246.898
```

In order to determine significance of each term in the model I remove each term from the model and then perform a likelihood ratio test to obtain a p-value for each term. For example:

```
#To determine significance of the 3-way interaction
model.count.nb.no3way<-glm.nb(X.total ~A+B+C+A:B+A:C+B:C, link = "log", data = count.X)
lrtest(model.count.nb, model.count.nb.no3way)#Interaction insignificant 

Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: X.total ~ A * B * C
Model 2: X.total ~ A + B + C + A:B + A:C + B:C
  #Df  LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
1  17 -1123.5                     
2  14 -1124.3 -3 1.6887     0.6394

#To determine significance of interaction between A and B
model.count.nb.noAB<-glm.nb(X.total ~ A+B+C+A:C+B:C, link = "log", data = count.X)
summary(model.count.nb.noAB)
lrtest(model.count.nb.no3way, model.count.nb.noAB)#Interaction insignificant 

Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: X.total ~ A + B + C + A:B + A:C + B:C
Model 2: X.total ~ A + B + C + A:C + B:C
  #Df  LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
1  14 -1124.3                     
2  11 -1125.8 -3 3.0111     0.3899
```

When determining the significance of either the 2-way or 3-way interactions only one term needs to be dropped from the model in order to use a likelihood ratio test however I am not sure which terms to drop if looking for the significance of the main effects and which model to compare this to. My first thought was to compare the model with no-3way interaction with the model without any terms involving a particular main effect i.e.:

```
model.count.nb.noC<-glm.nb(X.total ~ A+B+A:B, link = "log", data = count.X)
summary(model.count.nb.noC)
lrtest(model.count.nb.no3way, model.count.nb.noC)
```

The likelihood ratio test does work however, would this not represent the significance of C+A:C+B:C rather than just the main effect C.

Any help anyone can provide with my query would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If there are interactions in a model, the "main effects" (individual coefficients) of individual predictors can be difficult to interpret. For example, that "main effect" of a predictor can change if an _interacting_ predictor is centered or re-coded. The whole point of an interaction term is to allow the association of one predictor with outcome to depend on the value of one or more additional predictors. Please edit this question to be more specific about the hypotheses that you wish to test. For example: "is there _any_ association of `C` with outcome, considering all its interactions?"

Comment: @EdM My main hypothesis with the three way model is to ask if there is an association between the three factors in determining the number of events X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your stepwise approach, starting with the full model and then removing "insignificant" interaction terms, will make subsequent inference incorrect. Once you start using the results of a model to alter the model, the assumptions used for calculating *p*-values no longer hold. See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/124991/28500) and [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/544316/28500). I'll continue based on the full model with all pre-specified interactions.

Second, there's a problem defining a "main effect" for a predictor that's involved in an interaction. That's the case for any regression model. There's nothing specific here to a negative binomial model, except for the interpretation of coefficient estimates and some details of which versions of tests to perform. Some possibilities follow.

If you want to assess the overall importance of `C` in your full model, then what you want to evaluate *is* `C + A:C + B:C + A:B:C`. You could do that via a likelihood-ratio test. It can be more convenient to do a Wald "[chunk test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/27429/28500)" on all coefficients involving `C`.

At the other extreme, evaluating the "main effect" in terms of the *individual* coefficient for `C` in your model is a fool's errand. Changing the reference level (the level internally coded as 0) of either `A` or `B` would change the individual coefficient estimate for `C`, as they both interact with `C`. Changing the reference (0) level is the same as [centering a continuous predictor involved in an interaction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/65911/28500). The fundamental model and its predictions would be the same, but the value reported for the individual coefficient of `C` would be different and thus so would the apparent "significance" of its difference from 0.

You can perform some type of analysis of variance. If you have a perfectly balanced model, you could call `anova()` directly on your `model.count.nb`  object to get sequential likelihood ratio tests on all predictors and their interactions, via the `anova.negbin()` function that the [`MASS` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=MASS) invokes for such models. If the model isn't fully balanced, however, I think that [will give you problems](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13241/28500).

The `Anova()` function (note the capital "A") in the [`car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=MASS) can avoid the problems of imbalance. Applied to your `model.count.nb`  object, its default "Type-II" test would evaluate, for example, the significance of `C` after taking into account all terms (including interactions) *not involving* `C`. From the [help page](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/car/html/Anova.html):

> Type-II tests are calculated according to the principle of marginality, testing each term after all others, except ignoring the term's higher-order relatives.

It's also possible to perform "Type-III" tests, "testing each term in the model after *all* of the others." (Emphasis added.) [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20452/28500) outlines the different type of ANOVA calculations. To do that with `Anova()` in the `car` package you would have to re-code your predictors to use `contr.sum()` or another set of orthogonal contrasts (not the default "treatment" contrasts), as explained in the help page linked above. Alternatively, the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) can apparently perform Type-III tests without predictor recoding, according to the package's author in an [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/109468/28500) illustrating functions in its predecessor `lsmeans` package.

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/65917/28500) explains a way to get an effect measure for each of `A`, `B` and `C` in your model, evaluated by "averaging [predictor values] over the N cases that were actually observed." If you choose that approach, you can get standard errors and confidence intervals by combining the formula for the [variance of a weighted sum of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_correlated_variables) with the coefficient variance-covariance matrix.

Comment: In regards to the Anova() function,  in what circumstances would a type III anova be preferable over a type II? I have read online that a type II (because it does not take into account the interaction when calculating the SS of the main effects) is preferable if interactions are insignificant however most examples only consider the case where there is only one interaction (and two factors). In cases with more than 2 factors (such as in this case) would there have to be at least one significant interaction (either 2 or 3 way) to justify using a type III?

Comment: When using a type III approach how would using emmeans differ from a type I ANOVA?

Comment: @Insect_biologist if your observations are completely balanced among combinations of factor levels, then it won't matter which you use. If observations aren't balanced then Type I is useless, as the results will depend on the [order that predictors were included in the formula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13241/28500). I think that's also the case for the "sequential" method used by `anova.negbin()`.  The Type II versus Type III choice is a matter of dispute. See [these links](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=type+ii+iii+anova).

Comment: @Insect_biologist the ANOVA "significance" results for the combined 3-way interaction will be the same for all flavors of ANOVA, as all lower-level factors have already been accounted for. For evaluating the importance of individual predictors, what's wrong with things like `C + A:C + B:C + A:B:C`? That what [Frank Harrell's version of `anova()`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/rms/html/anova.rms.html) in his [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms/index.html) does. That particular function won't work on your negative binomial model, but the principle holds.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your primary goal is inferential, you should not base your model building strategy solely around statistical significance testing but also on what is theoretically or 'clinically' meaningful.

Is B an important potential effect moderator for the relationship of A and X.total? What about C? Then they should be included whether or not statistically significant.

There are also other measures you can use to help with model selection such as AIC/BIC and pseudo R-squared, but these come with their own limitations as well.